# can not run kibana due to authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

i got error when i run kibana.bat this is error below

```
Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: missing authentication credentials for REST request.
```

elasticsearch is running already.
any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: obligatory question: did you provide the authentication credentials to kibana?

Comment: i just provided authentication for elasticsearch how should i do that?

Comment: you should start from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/configuring-stack-security.html

Comment: is there a way to provice defult authentication for both? i just want to download run them after downloading without providing any authentication :)

Comment: if we're not talking of a production environment, then you could disable the security feature altogether ;) e.g., https://github.com/glenacota/elastic-training-repo/blob/main/clusters-to-go/elasticsearch/8.5.0/1es-1kibana.yml#L11

Comment: - xpack.security.enabled=false   i should take this in kibana.yml file yes?

Comment: elasticsearch.yml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252032/discussion-between-reza-setareh-and-glenacota).